# Batch file that creates a new batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file with code written in it from a batch file, so I tried this code:

```
Echo @echo off echo Hello pause > NewBatch.bat
```

But NewBatch.bat has all of those lines written in one single line. I kind of expected this this to happen, but is there any way I can make it write individual lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(   echo @echo off
    echo echo hello
    echo pause
) > NewBatch.bat
```

Comment: Thank you, this format was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
set /p n=^


Rem Above 2 lines are needed
Echo @echo off%n%echo Hello%n%pause > NewBatch.bat
```

And to ever produce a new line simply use `%n%`.

Mona.

Comment: Hmm... intersting idea, but when I run this code, the prompt opens, displays "@echo off" then closes (and doesn't create the batch file). Any ideas?

Comment: @Noodlebear Sorry, forgot the `/p` I've tested it and it now works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it in one line then this is an option:

```
(Echo.@echo off&echo.echo Hello&echo.pause)>NewBatch.bat
```

and a convoluted option:

```
>NewBatch.bat Echo.@echo off&>>NewBatch.bat echo.echo Hello&>>NewBatch.bat echo.pause
```